# I had getting this error on update function (Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on null)

Tags: laravel

```php
public function update(Request $request, $emp_id)
{
    $validator  = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'emp_code'      => 'required|max:255',
        'first_name'    => 'required|max:255',
        'last_name'     => 'required|max:255',
        'emp_image'     => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,PNG,JPEG,JPG|max:2048',
        'department'    => 'required|max:255',
        'designation'   => 'required|max:255',
        'joining_date'  => 'required|max:255',
        'offer_letter'  => 'required|mimes:doc,docx,pdf,DOC,DOCX,PDF|max:2048',
        'emp_email'     => 'required|email|max:255|unique:employees',
        'mobile_number' => 'required|regex:/^([0-9\s\-\+\(\)]*)$/|min:10',
    ]);

    $employeeimg = rand() . '.' . request()->emp_image->getClientOriginalExtension();
    request()->emp_image->move(public_path('images'), $employeeimg);

    $offerletter = rand() . '.' . request()->offer_letter->getClientOriginalExtension();
    request()->offer_letter->move(public_path('docs/new'), $offerletter);

    $form_data = array(
        'emp_code'      => $request->emp_code,
        'first_name'    => $request->first_name,
        'last_name'     => $request->last_name,
        'emp_image'     => $employeeimg,
        'department'    => $request->department,
        'designation'   => $request->designation,
        'joining_date'  => $request->joining_date,
        'offer_letter'  => $offerletter,
        'emp_email'     => $request->emp_email,
        'mobile_number' => $request->mobile_number,
    );

    $data = Employee::findOrFail($emp_id);

    //dd($form_data);
    $data->update($form_data);

    return redirect('employee')->with('msg_success', 'Employee updated successfully!');
}
```

I had getting error while updating the form with file uploads. and the error is

> Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on null

please give a solution for this

Comment: first check `$request->hasFile('emp_image')` then proceed to getClientOriginalExtension of file. or add to validation array **'emp_image' => 'file|required|image|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,PNG,JPEG,JPG|max:2048'**,

Comment: follow link [REF](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/requests#files)

Comment: can you please tell me in detail here         $employeeimg = rand() . '.' . request()->emp_image->getClientOriginalExtension();
    request()->emp_image->move(public_path('images'), $employeeimg);

Comment: $file = $request->file('emp_image'); and then $file->getClientOriginalExtension();

Comment: not getting bro.. still same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to check-in request `has` to file.

```
if($request->hasFile('emp_image')){
    if (Input::file('emp_image')->isValid()) {
        @unlink(IMG_PATH_URL.( $records->emp_image) );
        $file = Input::file('emp_image');            
        $ext  = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $mainFilename1 = rand().'.'.$ext;
        $file->move(public_path('images'), $mainFilename);            
    }
}


if($request->hasFile('offer_letter')){
    if (Input::file('offer_letter')->isValid()) {
        @unlink(IMG_PATH_URL.( $records->offer_letter) );
        $file = Input::file('offer_letter');            
        $ext  = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $mainFilename2 = rand().'.'.$ext;
        $file->move(public_path('docs/new'), $mainFilename);            
    }
}
```

Make sure You have added the enctype in form

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
</form>
```

Your controller should be like:

```
public function update(Request $request, $emp_id)
{
    $validator  = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'emp_code'      => 'required|max:255',
        'first_name'    => 'required|max:255',
        'last_name'     => 'required|max:255',
        'emp_image'     => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,PNG,JPEG,JPG|max:2048',
        'department'    => 'required|max:255',
        'designation'   => 'required|max:255',
        'joining_date'  => 'required|max:255',
        'offer_letter'  => 'required|mimes:doc,docx,pdf,DOC,DOCX,PDF|max:2048',
        'emp_email'     => 'required|email|max:255|unique:employees',
        'mobile_number' => 'required|regex:/^([0-9\s\-\+\(\)]*)$/|min:10',
    ]);

    $data = Employee::findOrFail($emp_id);
    if($data){

        $data->emp_code      = $request->emp_code;
        $data->first_name    = $request->first_name;
        $data->last_name     = $request->last_name;       
        $data->department    = $request->department;
        $data->designation   = $request->designation;
        $data->joining_date  = $request->joining_date;        
        $data->emp_email     = $request->emp_email;
        $data->mobile_number = $request->mobile_number;

        if($request->hasFile('emp_image')){
            if (Input::file('emp_image')->isValid()) {
                @unlink(IMG_PATH_URL.( $records->emp_image) );
                $file = Input::file('emp_image');            
                $ext  = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $mainFilename1 = rand().'.'.$ext;
                $file->move(public_path('images'), $mainFilename);
                $data->emp_image  => $mainFilename1;            
            }
        }

        if($request->hasFile('offer_letter')){
            if (Input::file('offer_letter')->isValid()) {
                @unlink(IMG_PATH_URL.( $records->offer_letter) );
                $file = Input::file('offer_letter');            
                $ext  = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $mainFilename2 = rand().'.'.$ext;
                $file->move(public_path('docs/new'), $mainFilename2);
                $data->offer_letter  => $mainFilename2;            
           }
        }

        if( $data->save() ) {
            return redirect('employee')->with('msg_success', 'Employee updated successfully!');
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: when i passed this $mainFilename in $form_data = array( 'emp_image' => '$mainFilename', ); getting undefined mainFilename

Comment: @JyothibabuNanipini So that `getClientOriginalExtension` null errors not occurs?

Comment: @JyothibabuNanipini As you right comment in one mistake: `$form_data = array( 'emp_image' => $mainFilename );` 
Don't wrap  `'` in variable.

Comment: @JyothibabuNanipini Both file names are not the same so use a different name. Of course, if the file not found then the variable is not defined errors. Now I will update the answer.

Comment: while upload the file and submitted getting the error.....(1/1) FatalThrowableError
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Input' not found

in EmployeeController.php (line 174)
at EmployeeController->update(object(Request), '25')
at call_user_func_array(array(object(EmployeeController), 'update'), array(object(Request), 'emp_id' => '25'))
in Controller.php (line 54)

Comment: @JyothibabuNanipini You should include facade `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;` in controller.

Comment: getting successfull message but not updating image

Comment: @JyothibabuNanipini I have also added a controller code for that.. use

Comment: @JyothibabuNanipini but not updating an image because new image added and old image as it is. If you like to change the image you need to `unlink()` first. 
`@unlink( IMG_PATH_URL.( $records->emp_image) );` before add.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW) at   $data->emp_code      => $request->emp_code,

Comment: can you please connect anydesk

Comment: @JyothibabuNanipini Sorry sorry i made mistake. Please use `=` instead of `=>`

Comment: @JyothibabuNanipini Use Updated answer. Refresh the page and see updated.

Comment: @JyothibabuNanipini `IMG_PATH_URL` means your folder URL path

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ','

in EmployeeController.php (line 176)

Comment: tq for resolving the issue.. please keep in touch with me.

Comment: @JyothibabuNanipini glad. Make answer as accept so that helps to someone.

Answer (score 1):

```
    public function update(Request $request, $emp_id)
    {
        $validator  = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'emp_code'      => 'required|max:255',
            'first_name'    => 'required|max:255',
            'last_name'     => 'required|max:255',
            'emp_image'     => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,PNG,JPEG,JPG|max:2048',
            'department'    => 'required|max:255',
            'designation'   => 'required|max:255',
            'joining_date'  => 'required|max:255',
            'offer_letter'  => 'required|mimes:doc,docx,pdf,DOC,DOCX,PDF|max:2048',
            'emp_email'     => 'required|email|max:255|unique:employees',
            'mobile_number' => 'required|regex:/^([0-9\s\-\+\(\)]*)$/|min:10',
        ]);

        $emp_img = $request->file('emp_image');

        $employee = rand() . '.' . $emp_img->getClientOriginalExtension();

        $emp_img->move(public_path('images'),$employee);




        $offer_letter = $request->file('emp_image');

        $offer = rand() . '.' . $offer_letter->getClientOriginalExtension();

        $offer_letter->move(public_path('docs/new'),$offer);



        $form_data = array(
            'emp_code'      => $request->emp_code,
            'first_name'    => $request->first_name,
            'last_name'     => $request->last_name,
            'emp_image'     => $employee,
            'department'    => $request->department,
            'designation'   => $request->designation,
            'joining_date'  => $request->joining_date,
            'offer_letter'  => $offer,
            'emp_email'     => $request->emp_email,
            'mobile_number' => $request->mobile_number,
        );

        $data = Employee::findOrFail($emp_id);

        //dd($form_data);
        $data->save($form_data);

        return redirect('employee')->with('msg_success', 'Employee updated successfully!');
    }



and in view form
     you have to add 
       <form action="" method="" enctype="multipart/form-data">

I Hope It Will Help You
```

Comment: still same error .. at  $employee = rand() . '.' . $emp_img->getClientOriginalExtension();

Comment: (1/1) FatalThrowableError
Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on null

in EmployeeController.php (line 175)
at EmployeeController->update(object(Request), '25')
at call_user_func_array(array(object(EmployeeController), 'update'), array(object(Request), 'emp_id' => '25'))
in Controller.php (line 54)

Comment: <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> their are  enctype="multipart/form-data" is important in form

Comment: <form name="userForm" action="{{URL::to('EmployeeController/update')}}/{{$employeedata->emp_id}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate="" autocomplete="off">\

Comment: try debug on every variable.. check where you wrong

Comment: if all get null... means something is wrong on your code.. try in update function on 1st line $test = Employee::where('id', $emp_id)->first(); then dd(); check it null or not\